# Not adding (non-retina) 1x images to an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Is there a way to not add 1x images to an iPhone/iPad app?

I'm developing an iPhone app and also testing on my iPad.
When I just use @2x images, the iPad successfully resizes down to the 1x size.

Is there any downside to not to add 1x images? Or are they still important?

Comment: regarding your question, ("Is there any way to not add 1x images to an iPhone app?"), the answer is YES: just don't add them and the @2x versions will work fine (performance hit aside)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By forcing the device to downsample, you're sacrificing performance and memory for a negligible amount of disk space. It's a really bad trade-off. Plus, downsampling a larger image on the fly on the device is likely to use a lower-quality downsampling algorithm than what's available in, say, Photoshop (for performance reasons).

Answer (score 0):

I had an app with 100+ near-fullscreen photos, and dropping the @1x versions made possible to keep the app below the 50 MB limit for downloading over a cellular connection.

In my case, I had no choice, but as @Kevin Ballard mentions, perhaps the trade-off is not worth it. Remember that non-retina images are 25% the size of the retina ones, so in terms of pixels you are only going from 1.25 to 1.00.

Granted, with compressed images the relation might not be linear (i.e., @1x PNG/JPEG may weight more than 1/4 of the equivalent @2x image on disk).